# Where should an Apache SSL certificate be generated?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl

I see different locations to store self-signed SSL certificates for Apache.

Which one should be used in which case?

1. /etc/ssl/certs/ (pem file) + /etc/ssl/private/ (for key file)
2. /etc/apache2/ssl/

Comment: They can be anywhere you like. `/my/secret/porn/folder/just/kidding` will work. Just make sure they're locked down so other users on the server can't read them.

Comment: @ceejayoz, that really is the answer, you should probably add it as one, so I can up-vote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They can be anywhere you like. `/my/secret/porn/folder/just/kidding` will work. Just make sure they're locked down so other users on the server can't read them.

I personally *prefer* the `/etc/ssl/certs` and `/etc/ssl/keys` approach, as I might switch to nginx or something - SSL certs aren't tied to a particular piece of server software. I've also seen them placed in the site's folder (i.e. `/srv/domain.com/ssl`), which can be nice organizationally.